# Xamarin Android Emulator Failed. Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Failed to generate Java type for class: Android.Support.V4.View.AsyncLayoutInflater/IOnInflateFinishedListenerImplementor due to MAX_PATH: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\php7\Mobile-Application\Glitch-Portal-Mobile-Application\GlitchPortal\GlitchPortal\GlitchPortal.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\AsyncLayoutInflater_OnInflateFinishedListenerImplementor.java'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.CopyIfStreamChanged(Stream stream, String destination)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.CreateJavaSources(IEnumerable`1 javaTypes, TypeDefinitionCache cache) GlitchPortal.Android
```

*------------------------------------This is the error I am getting -------------------------------
I also tried to mark Hyper-V from the 'Turn Windows features on or off' .But there is no Hyper-V option which is given in the picture. [I started with Xamarin.Form Blank]*
[image]

Comment: If you do not have this settings, Please check if you have met the requirement like this thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows#accelerating-with-hyper-v . If you cannot enable Hyper-V, you can enable HAXM as well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows#accelerating-with-haxm